# It happened when he was abroad. (4 versions of the sentence)

Tags: sentence-choice

> **It happened when he was abroad.**  [the main subject is "it"]
>
> **When it happened, he was abroad.**  [the main subject is "it"]
>
> **He was abroad when it happened.**  [the main subject is "he"]

As I understand it, all versions sounds fine. Only the main subject changes. We can't say the meaning is different, right? Only the emphasis is different.

*Addition:*

> **When he was abroad, it happened.**  [the main subject is "it"]

Does that sentence sounds good? It doesn't sound good in my native language.

Comment: The main subject of your second sentence is also "he" not "it."

Comment: Yes, they all mean the same.

Comment: Your extra version doesn't sound normal for most purposes. If you were talking about some long-awaited event, "At last, when he was abroad, it [finally] happened" would be a possible way to say it.